# How to style input element

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a button and checkbox.

```
<table class = "submit-css">
 <tr>
     <td>                    
         <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
         <asp:CheckBox ID="ckSendMail" runat="server" />
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I want to style those two items, but I don't know how to select them.

```
.submit-css input[submit]
 {
   //add rules here...
 }
```

I've tried the above selector but it's not working.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your button is of type `submit`, you can use the [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html):

```
.submit-css input[type="submit"] {
    // CSS rules here...
}
```

You can aslo reference just the IDs of the elements (i.e. `#btnSubmit` and `#chckSendMail`), or if you want to style both of them with some common rules, just leave off the attribute selector:

```
.submit-css input {
    // CSS rules here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To style the button, do this:

```
#btnSubmit
{
   // Your rules here...
}
```

To style the checkbox, do this:

```
#ckSendMail
{
   // Your rules here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.submit-css input
{
 // style properties..
}
```